# Working with object arrays in java

Tags: java

I'm working with object arrays in Java and it's just difficult for me to understand them, I guess it's just because I'm not use to them yet..

Basically what I'm trying to do is have an option menu come up.. when the user presses "1" (in the main application class) it brings them to another class (addVehicle())  where a Vehicle object is passed in as a parameter. (This all works fine)

At the top of this class I am limiting the vehicles to a maximum of 4:

```
Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[4];
```

And then here is the method that adds the vehicle:

```
public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    reader = new Scanner(file);
    if(canAddVehicle(vehicles[vehicles.length - 1]))
    {
        vehicle[vehicles.length - 1] = new Vehicle();
        vehicle[vehicles.length - 1].readRecord(reader);

        System.out.println("Vehicle Added!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You can not add more than 4 vehicles.");
    }
}
```

I would like it to store this vehicle object in the next spot in the array (if there is still a spot open) as well as all of the information that goes along with that Vehicle

Am I doing this the right way? Is this vehicle object correctly storing into the array? Should I be asking for information about the vehicle in my first class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you're not understanding what `vehicles.length` represents.

If you say:

```
Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[4];
```

then `vehicles.length` will *always* be `4`. That's the length of the array; It's fixed (you can't resize an array) and it doesn't matter that you haven't assigned anything to any of its elements yet. You will have four elements when you create the array, each containing `null`.

To do what you're trying to do using arrays, you have a couple options.

- Keep track of the last index you assigned a `Vehicle` to, starting with `0`
- Iterate through the array each time you want to insert and find the index of the first `null`. (Note this is a *very* inefficient way to do this)

The easier path would be to use one of Java's [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) that are dynamic and increase in size as you add things. An [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for example.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I though that the vehicles.length represented how many objects were currently in the array

Answer (score 1):

Nope. As you have specified the length of the `vehicles` array, the length will always return 4, so you'll always insert into the end of the array. Ideally, you need to keep a counter of the number of inserted elements if you want to do it this way (and check there's space!). Also, I don't know what your `vehicle` parameter is doing, as it doesn't seem to be used.

A *better* way to do this would be to use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), although of course, that won't help you if you want to learn how to use Object arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to use vehicles.length to count the amount of items already added. That's wrong. vehicles.length will always return 4. This a method to check the next available item (assuming that you still want to use arrays)

```
private <T> int nextAvailableIndex(T[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == null) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

You can use an ArrayList as suggested before. But, remember that ArrayList can grow indefinitely. Your code should look like:

```
List<Vehicle> l = new ArrayList<Vehicle>(4); // Initial/expected Capacity!

if(l.size() < 4) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution! Thanks for the help

```
     for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length || !found; i++)
            {
                if(vehicles[i] == null)
                {
                    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
                    vehicle[i] = new Vehicle();
                    vehicle[i].readRecord(reader);
                    found = true;
                    reader.close();
                }

            }
```